# How to use IF Then statements for minute of cell minus cell is equal to?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I wish to make an IF Then statement. Both cell A2 and A3 have dates in them. I want my IF Then statement to be if the minute of A3 minus the minute of A2 is equal to 1 then it performs my command. I also want to do an ElseIf Then statement for if the minute difference is 5 minute and if the minute difference is 15 minutes.

I tried finding the syntax online and have code copied below but it does not work. The code reads that if the minute value of cell A3 minus the minute value of cell A2 is equal to 1 then perform the function. It does not work though.

```
Sub ExportAverageData()

If (Minute(A3 - A2) = 1) Then
Sheets(2).Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C2,(ROW()-ROW(R2C5))*15,,15,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E9999")
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C3,(ROW()-ROW(R2C6))*15,,15,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F9999")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).ClearContents

ElseIf (Minute(A3 - A2) = 5) Then
Sheets(2).Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C2,(ROW()-ROW(R2C5))*3,,3,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E9999")
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C3,(ROW()-ROW(R2C6))*15,,15,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F9999")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).ClearContents

ElseIf (Minute(A3 - A2) = 15) Then
Sheets(2).Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C2,(ROW()-ROW(R2C5))*15,,15,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E9999")
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(R2C3,(ROW()-ROW(R2C6))*15,,15,))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F9999")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).ClearContents

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Minute(A3 - A2)`... `A3` and `A2` are not valid references to those cells. Perhaps `Range("A3")`... or `[A3]`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you that was the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help, I'm assuming that you are wanting to reference the values inside of cells A2 and A3, in which case you would need to also include the `Range()` and `.Value` tags.

```
If (Minute(Range("A2").Value) - Minute(Range("A3").Value) = 1) Then

'Do something

Else If (Minute(Range("A2").Value) - Minute(Range("A3").Value) = 5) Then

'Do something else

Else If (Minute(Range("A2").Value) - Minute(Range("A3").Value) = 15) Then

'Do something else

End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!